# How to distinguish between animations in animationDidStop (value for Key) in xCode (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, animation

I have two animations and I am trying to figure out which one ended, and then do what I want to do with it. I know i can distinguish between animations using valueForKey, but can't figure out the exact way.

```
 func myanimation1() {
let pulse1 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        pulse.duration = 0.25
        pulse.fromValue = 1
        pulse.toValue = 1.05
        pulse.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        pulse.autoreverses = true
        pulse.repeatCount = 2
       // pulse.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
      
        myImageView1.layer.add(pulse, forKey: myKey1)
}


 func myanimation2() {
let pulse2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
        pulse2.duration = 0.5
        pulse2.fromValue = 1.3
        pulse2.toValue = 1.5
        pulse2.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        pulse2.autoreverses = true
        pulse2.repeatCount = 4
       // pulse2.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
      
        myImageView2.layer.add(pulse, forKey: myKey2)
}
```

Now, how to do this bit please?

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
        
        
    //if pulse1 ended { do something }

    //if pulse2 ended { do something else }

        
    }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might keep the var as a property of your class, and compare that with the `anim` param of the delegate method, or find some way to identify it from `anim`. For instance, in your case the `duration` is different (but that would be a bad way to check which one), but you might retrieve them already:`if let pulse1 = myImageView1.layer.animation(forKey: myKey1), anim == pulse1 { ... } else if let pulse2 = myImageView2.layer.animation(forKey: myKey2), anim == pulse2 { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a really cool secret: you can use key-value coding to give your animation a name or other identifying mark.

```
let pulse2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale")
pulse2.setValue("pulse2", forKey:"name")
```

In the delegate method, you receive the animation, so you can check that name:

```
if let name = anim.value(forKey:"name"), name == "pulse2" ...
```

Comment: This is what I was after. Thank you.